# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Compaq Presario S4100NX

Tags: software-installation

This was marked as duplicate; however I have been unable to find answers to questions that describe my problem, 
or a fix;
 I am attempting install of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Compaq Presario S4100NX Celeron 2.5 ghz 1024 mb of ram NVIDIA 6200 512mb graphics card and a wireless N Wi-Fi. 
I get the install screen; however when I select install it says 0.64000 MP BIOS Bug 8254 not connected to timer IO APIC 
PLEASE!!! ANSWER me directly with exact steps to get this to install;
 marking this as duplicate leaving me to search on a wild goose chase is not helping me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to break up the giant block of text?  Maybe highlight what the actual error messages are?

Comment: This has been reported to Launchpad as a bug: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/265218